# how to define fiels in .new_activity with broghtway2 that have spaces in their name

Tags: python, brightway

When creating a new activity like so:

```
banana = database.new_activity(code='thisisthecodeforthebananamarket', 
                                            name='banana form havanna', 
                                            unit='kilogram', 
                                            type='process',                                                    
                                            location='CU')
```

(edit: originally I mistakenly used `.new_exchange()` in my example)

that all works fine, but if I want to define a field that has a space in its label such as `reference product` or `production amount`, this throws python off.

```
banana = database.new_activity(code='thisisthecodeforthebananamarket', 
                                            name='banana form havanna', 
                                            unit='kilogram', 
                                            type='process',
                                            production amount=1,                                                    
                                            location='CU')
```

I assume this should be assigned via a dictionary in some way, but I don't understand the structure of activities well enough to work out how exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you pass them as a dictionary it does indeed work. I've tried and it does not throw an error.

```
na = db.new_activity(code='thisisthecodeforthebananamarket', 
            name='banana form havanna', 
            unit='kilogram', 
            type='process',
            location='CU',
            **{'production amount':1})
            
assert na.valid()
```

Comment: oh thank you, seems like I copied the wrong code snippet to use an example. I will change it to .new_activity in the original post so that it won't confuse anyone with the same problem...

Comment: okk, I've updated the response to avoid confusion too